# How to save continuous 512 bytes into file using fprintf

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I want to save continuous 512 memory location values into csv file

```
        memcpy(signals, ascanSamples, ascanSizeInBytes);
        fprintf(fptr1, "%f,", *(signals));
```

Using fprintf how can i achieve it,.

I tried

```
fprintf(fptr1, "%f,", 512,512, *(signals)) but it is not working
```

Comment: What is `signals`? And `ascanSamples`?

Comment: First of all, only use the language tag of the language you're really programming in. Secondly, how about a loop?

Comment: Do you want to write 512 bytes, 512 floating point values or floating point values of a total size of 512 bytes?

Comment: `fprintf()` is for *printing*, i.e. converting values to textual form, which is rarely measured in "bytes" especially not when involving floating-point values. This is confusing.

Comment: Both are short variables and No looping used, One time I want to save 512 bytes from ascanSamples

Comment: We really need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you properly. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you want to do this in a single step, (i.e. with no loops) then the argument list in your `fprintf()` function will get unruly.  eg `fprintf(fp, "%f,%f,...(510 more)", v[0], v[1],...(510 more array elements) of unique values);`  If you were simply repeating the same value a number of times, consider using the _[%*f" form of printf and family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)_.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work, it will only output the first value (and also maybe because the type of `signals` is not `float` or `double`, you need to provide that information):

```
fprintf(fptr1, "%f,", *(signals));
```

And this cannot work because the arguments don't match the `fprintf` format string:

```
fprintf(fptr1, "%f,", 512, 512, *(signals))
```

Your question is somewhat unclear, but from  your comments I guess you might need something this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  short values[] = { 1,2,3,4 };  // your values (using 4 values instead of 512
                                 // for demonstration purpose)

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    printf("%f,", (float)values[i]);  // using printf instead of fprintf for
                                      // demonstration purpose
  }
}
```

You need a loop here, there is no way around.

Output

```
1.000000,2.000000,3.000000,4.000000,
```

For code that fits your needs more closely, we need to know the type of your `signals` variable.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are writing 512 bytes, you can use %c format specifier and iterate over signals 512 times.

Comment: I am writing short as float value

Comment: If you need to store 512 values, you can simply iterate 512 times and call fprintf("%f ,", signals[i])